Springboot Opentelemetry service name
We are using Springboot and micrometer based implementation for Opentelemetry with Jaeger as the collector. Everything works as expected in terms of sending the traces to Jaeger. One of the requirements is to change the name of a service being sent to Jaeger. From the docs, it looks like setting the SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME should work but it isn't. I have also tried setting spring.application.name in the application.yaml file with no luck.
Any one else experienced this issue and any idea why?
Thank you in advance!
SG

Have you defined OpenTelemetryConfig bean? It can overwrite the name for Opentelemetry.

Do you have an example? I think i did but not with much luck.
@Bean
public ResourceProvider serviceNameResourceProvider() {
return () -> Resource.builder()
.put("service.name", "my-custom-service-name")
.build();
}

Also i want to change the service name sent to Jaeger on traces not the entire service name which i can change with spring.application.name property
